# Displaying (installing) PWA banner in Android In-App browser not working

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I have a custom button that initiates PWA install banner. It works fine in computer, as well as in mobile browsers. Only if the web page is accessed through Android In-App browser, banner doesn't appear.

My code is as below:

```
<div class="center dp-px-1">
    <p class="">Please Click On <strong>INSTALL</strong> Button And Tap on <strong>Notification</strong> Shown At The Bottom To Install</p>
    <p class="" id="alreadyInstalled" style="display:none;color:red;">This app is already installed. If you think this is an error, please delete all browser cache and try again.</p>
    <p class="" id="installationStarted" style="display:none;color:green;">Installation Started...</p>
</div>

<div class="dp-width-100-p center dp-mt-2">
    <span style="width:50%;color:#ffffff;background-color:#666666;padding:5px 7px;" id="install" class="fallback dp-cursor-pointer">DEMO INSTALL</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let deferredPrompt;
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        deferredPrompt = e;
    });

    // Install Button installationStarted
    const alreadyInstalled = document.querySelector('#alreadyInstalled');
    const installationStarted = document.querySelector('#installationStarted');
    const installButton = document.querySelector('#install');
    installButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(deferredPrompt){
            deferredPrompt.prompt();
            deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
                if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                    console.log('User accepted the install prompt');
                    installationStarted.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    console.log('User dismissed the install prompt');
                }
            })
        } else {
            console.log('Already Installed');
            installButton.style.display = 'none';
            alreadyInstalled.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Most in-app browsers are based on webview which does not support PWA installability (nor several other PWA related APIs)

Comment: @MiguelGarcia thanks for that piece of information. Is there a way for the PWA app to avoid opening in in-app browsers then? Any code or workaround that can be implemented?

Comment: Unfortunately I think you need to treat in-app browsers as "old browsers" (like if you opened the page in IE11 o something like that). You can do feature detection and not show the option to install if not supported. You cannot prevent your site from opening in an in app browser since the host app typically requests to control all http/https links. In app browsers are know to be problematic because of that.